# VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to install kubeadm and for this i am trying to create vagrant environment i clone this link "https://github.com/kodekloudhub/certified-kubernetes-administrator-course" to my server and then run the command "vagrant up". I take this error.I am using  Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

==> kubemaster: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]

Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg*)" at line 95 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp

i want to create vagrant environment

Answer (score -1):

This problem was solved by downgrading the "VirtualBox" version. Try to install version 6.38.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).